# Add buttons programmatically Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create button in C# code using an existing Prefab. All I found on the website was something like

```
public GameObject a;
public RectTransform ParentPanel;
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        GameObject goButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(a); /error
        goButton.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
        goButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            Button tempButton = goButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}
```

In Unity project I have Prefab called "ButtonPrefab" where I put Button Object. There is an error in below line

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable a of NewBehaviourScript has not been assigned.
>   You probably need to assign the a variable of the NewBehaviourScript script in the inspector.

I am new to Unity. How is it come that not assigned var a can give me button using Instantiate()? And why do I have this error?

Comment: if it's just for debug you can probably get away with this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html

Comment: Do you drag and drob GameObject a from editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate prefabs very easily from within a Resources folder. Make a new folder within your project's Assets folder called Resources. It must be named Resources for this to work properly. Then you can make your button like this:

```
GameObject button = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myButton", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

Assuming your prefab is named "myButton."

Comment: Hi there so after this loop I am having 3 new GameObjects ? for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var button = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myButton", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;

Comment: Was that a question? If you instantiate the button three times you will get three new objects, correct.